# How to change the icon of the print preview dialogue in steema tchart?

Tags: c#, print-preview, teechart

I have Steema tchart in my windows form. whenever I try to print it and get the preview, it gives me the old icon on the top left corner .

Is there a way I can change the icon?
Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only option for now is either being a TeeChart source code customer and customizing the editors to fit your needs or create your custom editors inheriting existing classes as I explained [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=9763&p=40277&hilit=Change%20icon#p40296).